# Jquery Ajax Complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

We have a relatively simple Jquery Ajax script:

```
var k = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_rts=1&count=10&jsoncallback=";

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: k,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#ticker").append("<li>" + item.text + "</li>");
        })
    }
});
```

This works fine, but we want to use innerfade (a jquery script) to then fade in/out between these created li items.

Tried using complete but not sure I got it right, but it needs to be:

```
$('#ticker').innerfade({
                    animationtype: 'fade',
                    speed: 1500,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    type: 'random',
                    containerheight: '250px'
                    });
```

Basically, how can I incorporate this innerfade so it then animates the li items. I also tried calling this innerfade script after the ajax, but does not work (ie. nothing happens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var k = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_rts=1&count=10&jsoncallback=";

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: k,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#ticker").append("<li>" + item.text + "</li>");
        })
        $('#ticker').innerfade({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 1500,
            timeout: 2500,
            type: 'random',
            containerheight: '250px'
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NAjBL/)